# In new JavaScript API for Excel any change by an add-in clears the Undo/Redo stack

Tags: excel, office-addins, office365-apps, office365api

The Undo/Redo stack is cleared after running this simple code:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
    return ctx.sync(); 
});
```

Does anyone know how to fix or avoid this?

Comment: what happens in `ctx`? - the undo stack is normally cleared by any automation in Excel.

Comment: This code sample uses the new Javasciprt API for Excel and does nothing. The ctx.sync() synchronizes the state between JavaScript proxy objects and real objects in Excel.
You can read more about ctx in the following article on github:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/excel/excel-add-ins-programming-overview.md

Comment: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/10754784-fix-the-issue-with-new-javascript-api-for-excel-a was "started" at the time this comment was posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a side-effect of our APIs and there are currently no ways to prevent this. I'd suggest giving your feedback on the [Office JS's UserVoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/83526-office-js).

Gabriel Royer - Developer on the Office Extensibility Team, MSFT